# Monthly Sentinel-2A images in Google Earth Engine Code Editor

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

My goal is to get monthly Sentinel-2A imagens in Google Earth Engine Code Editor without need to change the date in the script, only using a scrollbar images fixed at monthly intervals for visualize one per month.

```
var sentinel_dry = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').
 filterDate('2017-07-01', '2017-09-30').
 filterBounds(plot).
 sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', true).
 first();
var sentinel_dry = ee.Image(sentinel_dry);

var sentinel_wet = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').
 filterDate('2016-10-01', '2016-12-31').
 filterBounds(plot).
 sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', true).
 first();
var sentinel_wet = ee.Image(sentinel_wet);
```

Comment: There are a lot of GEE example scripts by Google. Have a look into them to make this working. Maybe this one comes closest to yours: https://code.earthengine.google.com/6386ed1774df5824dc73c21084d352e0

Comment: That script is interesting, but I need a date (monthly) slider or range filter for image date.